# Resizing large image dataset with dlib

Tags: c++, xml, face-detection, dlib

I have a large face dataset (10k training, 5k validation images) with an image size of 5184x3456 and two XML files describing the training and validations sets (in dlib format, see below). I would like to train a deep neural network on this dataset for face detection using dlib. With the current image size, the training takes too much memory and time. Therefore, I would like to rescale the whole dataset.

Rescaling the images are easily achieved by using ImageMagick [convert](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php); however, of course I also need to change the pixel coordinates of the ground truth face boxes in my training and validation XML files appropriately so that the face boxes still fall on faces on the new, rescaled images. Those files have the following structure:

```
<image file="00056475158675a7f26160c17b6643bb.jpg">
  <box width="294" top="1245" height="354" left="753"/>
  <box width="210" top="639" height="366" left="309"/>
  <box width="222" top="9" height="228" left="4365"/>
</image>
<image file="0013609d9d3189887f659e1c0354ac3d.jpg">
  <box width="282" top="1029" height="402" left="225"/>
</image>
```

Is there a way to quickly rescale the box attributes (width, height, top, left) using dlib, or perhaps [imglab](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/tools/imglab)? Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? If those would be the coords of a rectangle (seem to be not; but you can easily transform this) and you downscale by a factor of 4, you just downscale those coords by a factor of 4 too. There are some things to consider depending on your exact scaling (jpeg probably has some mod 2/4/8 target = not all resolutions are possible; dlib probably expects an integer -> rounding). It's probably best to scale by constant factor, read out target size and build the quotients; then do the math and round. For some factors (e.g. / 4) no rounding (and read-out loop) should be needed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, these are actually the coordinates of a rectangle. Maybe the order is a bit confusing but they give the (top, left) coordinates plus (width, height) of the rectangular boxes. I downscaled the images by a factor of 4 and would like to apply the same to the XML files. What I wanted to know was whether there is a utility function in dlib or imglab that can do this in a simple way, or do I need to parse the original XML files and replace the coordinates with the downscaled ones using a Python script or something similar.

Comment: ```imglab -h``` does not indicate a built-in fuction imho.